# How to enforce generation of PDF table of contents?

Tags: hyperref, table-of-contents

When I'm adding `\tableofcontents` to my document the PDF generated contains a nice list of sections/subsections on the left side, when viewed in Adobe Acrobat (I also use `hyperref` package). Everything is fine.

But now I don't need this TOC to be visible in the document, but I want to keep it visible in the PDF. When I'm deleting `\tableofcontents` from the document it disappears in the PDF as well. How to solve it?

ps. Maybe this is the problem (my log)?:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Option `bookmarks' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 33.
```

Comment: Works for me (i.e. when using `hyperref` without `\tableofcontents`, I still get bookmarks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [what](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure#Sectioning_Commands) I've found and it works perfectly:

```
% ...
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\section*{Introduction}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a hack:

```
\newsavebox{\discard}
\sbox{\discard}{\vbox{\tableofcontents}}
```

The tableofcontents is generated and saved but never inserted into the document.

But I just read @lockstep's comment; you may not need any of this.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to use the [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) package or a tool like [pdfjam](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic/firth/software/pdfjam/) to remove the table of contents page(s) from the pdf file.

Other solutions involving modification of macros such as `\tableofcontents` and `\contentsline` require to know which document class you are using.
And of course you may create pdf bookmarks using `hyperref` commands yourself instead of using `\tableofcontents`.